# Ruby gtk2: button.sensitive = false - events still queue

Tags: ruby, gtk2

I use a button on my ruby gtk2 app which starts a longish job processing and I want to disable the button while processing so that the user can't accidentally run it twice.  I figured setting `button.sensitive = false` would do the job and tested it with the following code:

```
button.signal_connect(:clicked) do
  button.sensitive = false
  puts "clicked"
  sleep 5
  button.sensitive = true
end
```

Clicking on the button after the job has started still seems to put `:clicked` events on the stack so if I click the button twice more during the `sleep`, 'clicked' is displayed three times in the console window when I expected it would appear only once.

Do I misunderstand how this is meant to work?  If it won't work the way I expect, is there a way to clear the event stack once the job is finished?

Comment: Does not have the signal handler return to the main loop to become the setting effective ? Just guessing, do not worked with Gtk2 so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Torimus - pointed me in the right direction.  Apparently it helps if you read the documentation, specifically that of `Gtk.events_pending?`!   Added the following after setting `button.sensitive` to force the main loop to do its thing:

```
while Gtk.events_pending? do
  Gtk.main_iteration
end
```